# Show $S^n \setminus \{p,q\} $ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n \setminus\{0\}$.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism

Let $p$ and $q$ be the north pole and the south pole of the sphere $S^n$ respectively. I want to show $S^n \setminus \{p,q\} $  is diffeomorphic to the punctured plane $\mathbb R^n \setminus\{0\}$.

I know by stereographic projection that $S^n \setminus \{p\} $ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$, and $S^n \setminus \{p,q\} = \big(S^n \setminus \{p\}\big) \cap \big(S^n \setminus \{q\}\big)$, but I can't see further.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Stereographic projection gives diffeomorphism $f : \mathbb{S}\smallsetminus \{p\} \to \mathbb{R}^n$, with $f(q)=0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then the restriction of $f$ as map between open subsets $\mathbb{S}^n\smallsetminus \{p,q\} \to \mathbb{R}^n\smallsetminus \{0\}$ is also a diffeomorphism.

Comment: @Sou Thank you. Why not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stereographic projection is a diffeomorphism $f:\mathbb{S}∖\{p\}→\mathbb{R}^n$, with $f(q)=0∈\mathbb{R}^n$. So the restriction $\mathbb{S}^n∖\{p,q\}→\mathbb{R}^n∖\{0\}$ is the desired diffeomorphism.